# Auto-refresh partial view with JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a partial view that I am loading in using:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        @Html.Action("NewFaults", "Fault")
    </div>
</div>
```

This ultimately loads a partial view called `_NewFaults.cshtml` and I want to refresh every 10 seconds (for example) to regularly show any new faults that come in. I have been looking around online for how to do this for a while, but all the examples I find are very specific to their example and it's not obvious how to adapt them.

Can someone help me?

Comment: [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and [javascript timers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers)

Comment: Use `setInterval()` function on JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment, use a javascript timer

```
var timer = setInterval(YourFunction, 10000);
```

where YourFunction does an AJAX call to your controller for a partial view.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("Action","Controller")",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',        
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {
        //show it on page
    }
});
```

to such a method

```
public PartialView Action()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I applied the code above and was still having issues. I later found out that the controller action was defined as a Child Action only, which was stopping the call. Removing that made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval()` function.

```
 function myFunction() {
     setInterval(function(){ window.location.href='redirectURL.php' }, 10000); //Referesh particular page
//OR       
     setInterval(function(){ window.location.reload() }, 10000); //Referesh curent page    
    }
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp